# Please Help at locating elements in iframe. Using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, browser-automation

A noob here!

1. using google chrome in debugging mode.
2. there is no problem with accessing iframe, I can print the page source after switching to iframe.
3. successfully accessing any other part of the webpage with XPath.
4. the iframe is similar to a registration form with multiple pages
5. ```
   <iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin 
   allow-top-navigation allow-downloads allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"
   ```

Here is my code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9014")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\Users\\Hp\\chromedriver.exe", 
chrome_options=opt)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='ServiceScreen']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body-wrapper"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a').click()
```

I am trying to click on href/span/btn/input elements(code contains XPath for href), but failing with error "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"/similar. Been trying to click on different elements of iframe with different find_element....click() methods but none seems to work.

Appreciate any kind of information on this topic.

Comment: What web page are you trying to access and what element there are you trying to click?

Comment: @Prophet it is not a publicly available website and form, unfortunately, I cannot share it. Various elements, 1st href to get to the second page of the form(iframe) and on 2nd page there are li, span, input, select and btn that I need to click on

Comment: Well, I'm not sure we can help in this case...